# How to create a workable leaf spring in Blender?

Tags: physics

I want to create a leaf spring which can be used in a physical simulation to spring away the objects when it is being deformed. Should I use a soft body to do this? However, it doesn't seem like soft bodies could accomplish this.

Comment: I am not sure if any object would be suited for that. The easiest way is probably to solve the Differential equation and hardcode this function to the spring. (You could just take a sinus function with exponantial decrease in Amplitude)

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PGzy3B9vw0g ?

Answer (score 7):

This is the closest simulation I could think of ([also made video version available](http://youtu.be/7MtJzxrfac8)):

1. Create a Cube <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd><kbd>m</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> and scale down it <kbd>s</kbd><kbd>z</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd>.
2. Create and instance with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd>. Repeat several times with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, making sure to end with an uneven amount.
3. Select all newly created cubes and and make active rigid bodies <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>.
4. In the the Tool Shelf under Rigid Body Tools, click Calculate Mass and select Steel.
5. One by one go along selecting each of the neighbouring cubes and click the Connect button (also in the Rigid Body Tools).
6. Finally select the centre cube and set it to passive <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>.

[image: Example result]

Comment: It's just a one minute video, you don't have to go into too much detail, just leave a useful summary here. Link only answers aren't recommended, because if the link goes *(ie, the video gets pulled)*, so does the answer.

Comment: You can definitely write this explanation out. It really isn't that long. Take some screenshots of the relevant portions, like where you set the middle piece to passive, and you should be good to go. Nice effect, by the way.

Comment: the one-by-one part can be vastly sped up with this addon: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?275823-WIP-Bullet-Constraints-Tools-0-3-7